# Inserting a unique random alphanumeric number in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, random

I want to generate a unique random alphanumeric number in mysql so that every entry in the database is retrieved by that number and moreover it wont be a sequence which the client can recognise. Please let me know how can I generate such a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below sql give you random alpha numeric number.

```
     SELECT CAST(CONCAT( CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65),FLOOR(100+RAND()*(500-100)))
 AS CHAR(50))AS random_alpha_numeric
```

you can generate range of random number like these.

syntax: `FLOOR(min_value+RAND()*(max_value-min_value))`

You can insert random alpha numeric number in to table like below.

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (column_name ) VALUES( CONCAT( 
CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65),FLOOR(100+RAND()*(500-100))))
```

Thank you.

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(     CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65),FLOOR(100+RAND()*(500-100))) AS 
random_alpha_numeric

Comment: can you provide what type of output you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate an unique random number. Over time, the randomness will generate a number already stored.
You need to make a "quasi-random" number, meaning that it's a number based on another data, but it just looks random. You can use the primary key on the table as the base number to generate the "fake-random" number

```
INSERT INTO myTable(primaryKey,quasiRandom) 
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(primaryKey),0)+1, CAST(CONCAT(IFNULL(MAX(primaryKey),0)+1,CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65),FLOOR(100+RAND()*(500-100))) AS CHAR(50)) AS random_alpha_numeric FROM myTable;
```

Comment: i made a unique random alphanumeric number by using java and connected it to database.